# How do hardware-accelerated toolkits like Qt & JavaFX enable quality font rendering?

Tags: qt, opengl, javafx, 3d, direct3d

Given that neither OpenGL nor Direct3D support high-quality font rendering (such as LCD rendering), how do toolkits which render their UIs using one of these hardware graphics APIs manage to integrate such quality text within a 3D or 2D "scene"?

Are they calling platform-specific APIs (such as DirectWrite on Windows) to render the text into some kind of image buffer which is then displayed in the scene (maybe as a texture or whatever else is available)?

Comment: All generic text rendering is done on the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Usually they use a glyph rasterizer and text layout libraries that run on the CPU to render whole paragraphs of text into a picture. That picture is then loaded to the GPU where it's drawn at the desired place.

A number of people (including me) are working on GPU accelerated all-purpose glyph rendering, that doesn't rely on a lot of preprocessing. There are a number of interesting approached which got published over the past few years, but no gold-standard solution so far.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the basic idea I had. But it sounds so inefficient and I still don't understand why OpenGL for example does not have built-in support for crisp font rendering. Others have told me that the APIs and the drivers are optimised mostly for games where quality text is rarely required. Do you have any links to the kind of research you are referrring to? Is that things like distance field fonts? I know there's a library named freetype-gl but it basically uses FreeType for rasterisation and then it's rendered into the scene. I am very interested in GPU-based font handling.

Comment: @ClancyMerrick: Because glyph rendering is frickin' difficult. That's why. The problem is, that GPUs "think" in terms of primitives delimited by linear boundaries (points, lines, triangles). Being linear means, that for every point (i.e. pixel in the framebuffer) you can exactly tell, which input values map to it. Glyphs OTOH consist mainly of curves, of 3rd order to spice things up. The problem this causes is, that it is mathematically proven, that there are not generalized closed solutions for fining the roots of a 3rd order curve.

Comment: @ClancyMerrick: What this boils down to is, that  that scanline conversion of Glyph outlines is a problem that doesn't cater that well to the way GPUs work. You can tesselate curves to triangulated meshes just fine, of course.  But you can do that only up to a certain resolution until you drop below a certain minimum area threshold below which GPUs can't fully parallelize primitive rendering. That's why you want a list of scanline ranges, but those doesn't parallelize that well; essentially you have to iteratively trace the curve, piece by piece, with every step adjusting the increment.

Comment: @ClancyMerrick: This is why people like me are working on schemes that project the outline representation of glyphs into a different space and representation, that's far better suited for GPU rendering. My method works well enough for "non-decorative" latin characters, but there's still lot of problems for decorative fonts or east asian scripts.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed info. Do you have any links to the work you are doing or to similar work by others?

Comment: @ClancyMerrick: Here's a medium post which is very similar to my approach (I had about the same idea as Blinn et. al at Microsoft, but they beat me to it with an implementation): https://medium.com/@evanwallace/easy-scalable-text-rendering-on-the-gpu-c3f4d782c5ac – it's not surprising though. We graphics people are all reading the same publications and have to work with the same tools, so we usually arrive at similar conclusions and ideas. Also a main reason why software patents are vile.

Comment: How would someone write their own implementation without violating not just the Microsoft patents but also the Adobe and NVIDIA patents mentioned in the article? Would it be OK in an open source project? And what would happen if your implementation was used commercially?

Comment: @ClancyMerrick: Truth to be told: I don't effin care… as long as I don't commerzialize my work outside the EU there's little problems for me, because pure software patents simply are not enforcable here (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_patents_under_the_European_Patent_Convention ) and as far as computer graphics are concerned *everything* boils down to pure math almost immediately. Is it okay to use this stuff in libre software. The EFF would say "no!"; I say "yes!" you just have to wait a couple of years before it can be used freely. Case in point MP3, last week.

Comment: @ClancyMerrick: That's not to say that courts here made a few horrendous decisions, but if push comes to shove I can always reformulate *any* computable algorithm (which means *any* computable program) into terms of lambda calculus and from there rewrite it as something that's entirely mathematical. For much of computer graphics it's actually trivial, because most of the papers in which research is presented formulate the methods in terms of calculus and linear algebra anyway. IANAL, but that pretty much boils down to attempting to patent math, which technically is not allowed.

Comment: @datenwolf: "it is mathematically proven, that there are not generalized closed solutions for fining the roots of a 3rd order curve" -- That's actually the case for polynomials of degree 5 or higher.  While there are generalized formulas for degree 3 and 4, they can be quite cumbersome, much more so than the quadratic formula taught in high school algebra.

Comment: @PeterO. The case of polynomials of 5th and higher degrees is an interesting one. There's indeed no generalized formula if you're limited in your lexicon of functions. If all you can do is +−*/^ and roots, then yes, that's not enough to express a closed form solution. But if you're willing to expand the lexicon with just one more function (there's several choices for it!), you can indeed express a closed-form solution to 5th degree polynomials. This approach works for for polynomials of any higher degree. Machines are very good at generating and applying those solutions. Humans - not so much.

Comment: @KubaOber: I was referring in my previous comment to the Abel-Ruffini theorem, also known as Abel's impossibility theorem, where the limitation of operations exists, which I didn't take account of.

Comment: Another way to look at it: humans tend to think of closed form solutions as something nice, small, tidy and elegant. The cubic solution teeters on the edge of admissibility here, and the quartic solution is already outlandish enough that *both* humans and machines get results quicker if they find the roots using general purpose numerical iterative solving algorithms. The iterated zeroes can also be more accurate than the closed form ones in all cases, even for a quadratic function. The solution for 5th degree polynomials barely fits on a page, and it only gets worse from there on.

Answer (score 1):

All text rendering in Qt 5, so far, always starts with the CPU-based raster backend.

In Qt 5, there are three text rendering modes:

1. `QWidget` - raster backend output is used directly, there's no hardware acceleration.
2. `QOpenGLWidget` - the raster backend renders to a texture (perhaps a [font atlas](http://wdobbie.com/freetypeglatlas.png)), the texture is then displayed on triangles. Zooming in causes obvious pixellation.
3. Qt Quick (in QML) uses Valve's [Signed Distance Field](https://youtu.be/CGZRHJvJYIg) text rendering, and is done on the GPU based on a precomputed distance field texture. The texture comes from the raster backend, but doesn't directly represent the text you see.

   The SDF representation allows cheap text styling - outlines, glows and drop shadows are computed by the GPU as well, based on the same texture.

   See [this blog entry](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/07/15/text-rendering-in-the-qml-scene-graph/) for details of Qt's implementation.

See [this comparison video](https://youtu.be/M4waDSXWGGw) between the three.

There are much better approaches now, where the rasterization is done completely on the GPU using an outline font representation of a string of quadratic splines. As with all good things, the problem is that some of those methods are patent-encumbered :( They do allow for easy addition of effects such as outlines.

See [this webgl/javascript War and Peace reader (sic!)](http://wdobbie.com/warandpeace/) implementation that adaptively switches between GPU rasterization (at glyph sizes above a dozen pixels or so) and a font atlas (at smaller sizes) to render 1300 pages of text at realtime frame rates.

See [this webgl/javascript equation renderer](http://thetamath.com) for not only realtime rendering of text, but also realtime rendering of math equations, even those without closed-form formulas. As it turns out, you don't need closed-form formulas to draw as-if there was a closed-form formula :)